# revoscaler sqlServerdData rxImport uniqueidentifier column failed

Tags: sql-server, r, revoscaler

I'm trying to import data from SQL Server, but I'm having issues importing a table which consists of uniqueidentifier column type.

I'm using R Client 3.3.2.0 to query database.

Database table:

[image]

Code:

```
sqlConnString = "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;SERVER=JDIMKO;DATABASE=Test;UID=sa;PWD=***;"

colClasses = c("id" = "integer", "ui" = "character")

sqlServerData <- RxSqlServerData(
    sqlQuery = "select * from tbl1",
    connectionString = sqlConnString, colClasses = colClasses)

custData = rxImport(sqlServerData)
```

Error:

```
Unhandled SQL data type!!! 
Unhandled SQL data type!!! 
Could not open data source.
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  Could not open data source.
```

Comment: It looks like revoscaler utility is missing support for uniqueidentifier column type

Comment: we can skip uniqueidentifier column by changing sqlQuery, as a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RxSqlServerData` not supported `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type. You should convert it to varchar.

```
sqlServerData <- RxSqlServerData(
    sqlQuery = "select id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), ui) ui from tbl1",
    connectionString = sqlConnString, colClasses = colClasses)
```